# Definition of Generalised Coordinates: Confusion with Notation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

My analytical mechanics lecturer gave a definition for Generalised Coordinates today, it is as follows:

> Generalised Coordinates: Let $(q_1,q_2)\in\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x=x(q_1,q_2)$ and $y=y(q_1,q_2)$ with the local condition $$det\bigg(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(q_1,q_2)}\bigg)\neq0$$

I know that the matrix is supposed to consist of $x$ and $y$ differentiated with respect to $q_1$ and $q_2$, but I'm not sure which column/row corresponds to $x$ or $y$ and which column/row corresponds to $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2}$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: $J=\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial q_{1}} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial q_{2}} \\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial q_{1}} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial q_{2}}
\end{pmatrix} $ But$ det(J)=det(J^T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure which column/row corresponds to $x$ or $y$
> and which column/row corresponds to $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}$
> or $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}$.

It doesn't matter.
Changing the sequence of rows, changing the sequence of columns,
or even swapping rows with columns
does not change the determinant at all, or only changes its sign.

You see this by spelling out the matrix and the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):

$$
det\left(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(q_1,q_2)}\right)
= det\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1} &
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2} \\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_1} &
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_2}
  \end{pmatrix}
= \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1} \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_2}
 -\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2} \frac{\partial y}{\partial q_1}
$$